# How to pass jQuery ng-repeat {{x.something}} to javascript api url like /api/get_now/{{x.something}}

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to pass jQuery ng-repeat `{{x.something}}` to javascript URL ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            let address = '<?=ROOT_ADDRESS?>/api/get_now/{{x.something}}';
            $.ajax({
                url: address,
                success: function (data) {
                    data = $.parseJSON(data);
                }
            });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not have ng-repeat but if you need how to get x.something value in address variable you can use JavaScript interpolation using back-ticks.

let address = `<?=ROOT_ADDRESS?>/api/get_now/{{x.something}}`;

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    let x = {something:"123"};
    let address = `<?=ROOT_ADDRESS?>/api/get_now/${x.something}`;
    alert(address)
    $.ajax({
        url: address,
        success: function (data) {
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This might solve your problem.

Good day :)